# Creating an object-oriented AngularJS model with Restangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular, code-cleanup

I'm new to Angular and trying to figure out how to create a model to clean up my controller. I'm using Restangular and have created a factory that returns a model object.

I thought that I could do something like this...

**model**

```
Testimonials.factory('Testimonial', ['Restangular', function(Restangular) {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    function Testimonial() {
        // public properties, assigned to the instance ('this')
    }

    Testimonial.prototype.all = function() {
        return Restangular.all('testimonials').getList();
    }

    /**
     * Return the constructor function
     */
    return Testimonial;
}]);
```

**controller**

```
Testimonials.controller('TestimonialsController', ['$scope', 'Testimonial', function($scope, Testimonial) {

    Testimonial.all.then(function (testimonials) {
        $scope.testimonials = testimonials;
    });
}]);
```

I am receiving the error in chome dev tools, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

How can I make this work? And is this a good way to implement a model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, you are missing the parentheses in your `all` method:

change:

```
 Testimonial.all.then(function (testimonials) {
        $scope.testimonials = testimonials;
 });
```

to:

```
 Testimonial.all().then(function (testimonials) {
        $scope.testimonials = testimonials;
 });
```

and you also need to return a new instance of `Testimonial` in your factory:

change:

```
return Testimonial;
```

to:

```
return new Testimonial();
```